# Overwriting values of hashmap in bash

Tags: bash, shell, hashmap, environment-variables

I have declared a hashmap in my bash script whose value is dependent on my environment variable.

```
export test_ENVIRONMENT=1

if [ -z "$test_ENVIRONMENT" ]; then
    echo "Environment variable test_ENVIRONMENT is not set."
    exit 1
fi

echo $test_ENVIRONMENT;
hashmap["1"]="1"
hashmap["2"]="2"

MySql="select distinct url as urls from t where
 REGION=${hashmap["$test_ENVIRONMENT"]} 
 and visitday >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-5,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
 AND visitday <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
 order by urls ;"

echo $mySql
exit;
```

I am running the script three times with different values of test_environment

1. `export test_environment=1`
2. `export test_environment=2`
3. `export test_environment=1`

In last two times, my region value is set to 2 rather than 1.

i.e On setting different values for test_envoironment, the second value is always overwriting the initial value. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Two of your three `test_env` example values are identical

Comment: And is that your whole script? Don't you have a  `declare` somewhere?

Comment: Found a similar problem here :http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-fake-associative-arrays-in-bash.html . Is there any clean way to do this?  @Mat: declare is not compulsory( atleast in version-3.2 its not a mandte)

Comment: It is for associative arrays I believe. You get an indexed array otherwise.

Comment: @Mat, can you please help me understand

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `bash --version`.

`Associative array` is supported after bash **4.0**.